# How do I save and retrieve an array of doubles to/from NSUserDefaults?

Tags: ios, objective-c

What is the correct syntax to save and retrieve an array of doubles to/from NSUserDefaults please?

I know that I have to wrap it inside an NSObject, but don't exactly know how...
Many thanks

Comment: `NSArray` (or `NSMutableArray`) full of `NSNumber` objects will get you there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
NSArray *doubles = @[@(1.0), @(1.2), @(1.5)];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:doubles forKey:@"myDoublesKey"];

doubles = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"myDoublesKey"];
```

Then you can iterate the array of NSNumbers and get back doubles like this:

```
for (NSNumber *number in doubles) {
    double num = [number doubleValue];
}
```

To get NSNumbers without Objective C's verbose syntax one can do:

```
double num = 1.2;
NSNumber *number = @(num);
```

This is the same as:

```
double num = 1.2;
NSNumber *number = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:1.2];
```

Comment: I get you +1, but may be you can also add how to confer double to NSNumber without using literals : `NSNumber *number = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:1.0];`

Comment: Many thanks for this. I am however having issues in implementing this as my double array was actually declared using C. I used: double DOUBLESarray[ArrayLength]. I believe I cannot store this directly but I don't know how to wrap it inside an NSObject....

Comment: Can you post the code in your question then? Also, may I ask why you can't just declare the array using Objective-C? Another option is to convert the C array to an NSArray before persisting.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I converted to an NSArray and then it did work.